# How can I sort a subset of a list by referencing the index of every subsets' element in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Consider a list and a subset of the list like this:

```
v = [1,2,4,5,2,8,1] (index = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
v_sub = [1,2,8,4,1] (corresponding index in v = 0,1,6,2,7)
```

And I coded like this:

```
v_sub.sort(key=v.index)    #Or v_sub.sort(key=lambda x: v.index(x))
print(v_sub)               #[1, 1, 2, 4, 8]
```

I wanted to sort v_sub by its corresponding index in v in an increasing way.That means [0,1,2,6,7].So I thought it would give me [1, 2, 4, 8, 1] but it didn't.How can I correct my code in a terse way?

Comment: *I thought it would give me [1, 2, 4, 1]*. Well it was like so already. Also, can you please elaborate more on your expected output and the logic behind it?

Comment: @Kasramvd is right. The indices of a list's elements are created as elements are inserted into the list. So, a list is already sorted by indices.

Comment: Because `index` gives *the first index*.

Comment: `L.index()` stops at the index of the first occurrences of a given elements. Thus, both ones are using the same index to be sorted.

Comment: @Kasramvd Thx, I corrected my spelling and used another example.

Comment: @algerbrex Extractly! So how can I implement the sort in a subset including duplicate elements? I think I can set a flag of the element in v to warm me that it is already processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate values in *v*, so you need to mark each of them as soon as you have used them:

```
v = [1,2,4,5,2,8,1]
v_sub = [1,2,8,4,1]

def indexAndClear(v, x):
    i = v.index(x)
    v[i] = None # This index should not be returned a second time
    return i

vCopy = v[:] # to make sure we do not mutate v in the process
v_sub.sort(key=lambda x: indexAndClear(vCopy, x))
print(v_sub)
```

Comment: Yes, a flag to mark if it is processed in v_sub is the key.